# Use `compilerOptions.baseUrl` with Vite.js project?

Tags: vite, esbuild

I'm trying to migrate from Create React App to Vite.js, but I'm having issues with the import aliases.

In Create React App I have a `jsconfig.json` file with `compilerOptions.baseUrl` set to `src`, so that if I `import Comp from 'components/MyComponent` it gets automatically converted to a relative import that points to `src/components/MyComponent`.

I can't understand how to achieve the same with Vite.js and esbuild?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the comment, using config option `root` of `vite` and **setting an alias** is not an option.

The solution presented here is to buid dynamicaly aliases.

Assuming a folder hierarchy like the following :

```
root_project
│   README.md
│   package.json    
│
└───resources
│   │   index.html
│   |   app.js
│   |___components
|   |   |
|   |   |___ HelloWorld.svelte
|   |
│   │___assets
|   |   |
|   |   |___css
|   |   |   |
|   |   |   |___app.scss
|   |   |   
|   |___config
|   |   |
|   |   |___index.ts
│   |
└───node_modules
```

in `vite.config.js`

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import path from 'path'
import { readdirSync } from 'fs'

const absolutePathAliases: { [key: string]: string } = {};
// Root resources folder
const srcPath = path.resolve('./resources/');
// Ajust the regex here to include .vue, .js, .jsx, etc.. files from the resources/ folder
const srcRootContent = readdirSync(srcPath, { withFileTypes: true }).map((dirent) => dirent.name.replace(/(\.ts){1}(x?)/, ''));

srcRootContent.forEach((directory) => {
  absolutePathAliases[directory] = path.join(srcPath, directory);
});

export default defineConfig({
  root: 'resources',
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      ...absolutePathAliases
    }
  },

  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: '/main.ts'
    }
  }
});
```

Now, you can include a component without changing your imports directive :

```js
import HelloWorld from 'components/HelloWorld.svelte'
```

You can also include files directly from `resources` folder:

```js
import { foo } from 'config'
```

Same for assets and other files under `resources` or global libs:

```js
import path from 'path'               // <--- global
import { foo } from 'config'          // <--- resources
import logoUrl from 'assets/logo.png' // <--- resources
```

More info there: [vite official doc](https://vitejs.dev/config/#resolve-alias)

Comment: I am receiving This localhost page can’t be foundNo web page was found for the web address: http://localhost:3000/
HTTP ERROR 404 :c

Comment: @Jesús you could make another question, providing what you've tried and sharing your project config to get better help. The 404 error mean it's working but there is an issue in the config somewhere. I bet on a bad path of the `index.html` file.

Comment: This worked for me whitout replacing regex. Maybe it's because I'm using @mui/material library.