# Absolute imports in vite from src

Tags: typescript, vite

Which config files need to be adjusted in a react + ts + vite setup, in order to import files like so:

`import x from 'src/components/x'`

With the basic setup, we end up with:

`Failed to resolve import "src/components/x" from "src/components/y.ts". Does the file exist?`

Answer (score 0):

Found a working [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69424422/use-compileroptions-baseurl-with-vite-js-project)

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import path from 'path'
import { readdirSync } from 'fs'

const absolutePathAliases: { [key: string]: string } = {};
// Root resources folder
const srcPath = path.resolve('./resources/');
// Ajust the regex here to include .vue, .js, .jsx, etc.. files from the resources/ folder
const srcRootContent = readdirSync(srcPath, { withFileTypes: true }).map((dirent) => dirent.name.replace(/(\.ts){1}(x?)/, ''));

srcRootContent.forEach((directory) => {
  absolutePathAliases[directory] = path.join(srcPath, directory);
});

export default defineConfig({
  root: 'resources',
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      ...absolutePathAliases
    }
  },

  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: '/main.ts'
    }
  }
});
```

Not sure if a better/simpler approach exists. I'd expect something as simple as baseUrl in a typescript config to work, but can't find anything comparable.